# Roots of polynomials in two variables

Tags: polynomials, euclidean-algorithm

Let $f \in k[x,y]$, $k$ is a field of characteristic zero.
Assume that $(a,b) \in k^2$ is a root of $f$, namely,
$f((a,b))=0$.

> Is it true that $(x-a)(y-b)$ divides $f$, namely,
>   $f=(x-a)(y-b)g$, for some $g \in k[x,y]$?

Of course, in case of one variable, if $a \in k$ is a root of $f \in k[x]$,
then $f=(x-a)g$, see [this](http://mathrefresher.blogspot.co.il/2008/01/roots-of-polynomials.html).

**Remarks:** (1) The answers of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32070/what-is-the-algorithm-for-long-division-of-polynomials-with-multiple-variables) are perhaps relevant.
(2) Perhaps we should consider the given $f \in k[x,y]$ as a polynomial in one variable $x$ over the integral doamin $k[y]$ and also as a polynomial in one variable $y$ over $k[x]$.

> **Edit:** After receiving a comment with a counterexample, what if we further assume that $(a,b)$ is also a root of $f_x$ and a root of $f_y$; is now $(x-a)(y-b)$
>   necessarily divides $f$?

Perhaps the answer is positive by considering $f \in k[y][x]$ and $f \in k[x][y]$, though I am not sure, since it is just one point $(a,b)$, not a line.
An example I had in mind is: $f=xy=(x-0)(y-0)$, $(a,b)=(0,0)$, $f_x=y$, $f_y=x$.
Notice that also $(x,0)$ and $(0,y)$ are roots of $f$, so regardless of the derivatives, $(x,0)$ being a root of $f$ implies that $y-0$ divides $f$, and $(0,y)$ being a root of $f$ implies that $x-0$ divides $f$.
Perhaps the resultant will help?

The answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/597399/is-there-a-generalization-of-factorization-involving-roots-for-multivariate-po?rq=1) seems relevant, especially:
"if $p=p(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n)$ is a polynomial over an algebraically closed field $F$ and $q$ is a nonzero polynomial over $F$ in $n$ variables which is irreducible, and such that $q(X)=0\implies p(X)=0$, then $q$ divides $p$. This follows from Hilbert's Nullstellensatz", which is probably very close to what I was looking for.

Comment: Try $a=b=0$ and $f(x,y)=x+y$.

Comment: Thank you, nice counterexample. So there is no hope to get a similar result to what I suggested?

Comment: There is no direct equivalent, see however [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/247421/polynomial-remainder-theorem-for-bivariate-polynomials) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/316752/division-algorithm-for-multivariate-polynomials).

Comment: For your update, along the lines of dxiv's comment, consider $f(X, Y) = X^{2}+Y^{2}$ and $a = b = 0$.

Comment: Thanks. Nice counterexample for my edit/update..